# Browser-level DNS settings, to work like the hosts file at system level

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, hosts-file

The web application we develop is doing certain things depending on the domain and subdomains in the address. To be able to develop and test everything on a local environment, one would need to bind the domains to 127.0.0.1, using the hosts file.

However, this would cut that machine off from accessing the live server domains.

**Question**: Is there a browser-level hack that allows one to do *hosts*-like stuff,  only for that browser?

UPDATE: A proxy .pac file can do this just fine. Like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
      if (shExpMatch(url,"*.example.com/*")){
         return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:80";
      }
   }
```

Yay!

Comment: Searching for Firefox add-ons here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?pp=20&pid=1&cat=all&q=domain+ip&lver=any&page=2 only returns one possibly useful, but limited to Linux. We also use Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do pretty clever things with a [proxy auto-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file.  Try one that returns `PROXY 127.0.0.1:80` for the domains you want affected and `DIRECT` for the rest.

Comment: This works great! And with an extension like Proxy Switchy for Chrome I'm all set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a HTTP proxy that will do what you want?